# 'Teeworld' to 'teeworlds'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-rename-request

Can the tag [teeworld](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teeworld) be changed to [teeworlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teeworlds)?
It [seems](https://store.steampowered.com/app/380840/Teeworlds/) [that is](https://teeworlds.com/) the correct spelling.

It was probably created too hastily for [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378161/how-to-capture-a-flag-in-teeworld).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!